# Adding many markers on google map causes rough map movement

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm developing an android app in which I need to add multiple markers (max 100) on the google map. everything is OK but when I run it on a 10" tablet, the map does not move smoothly with multiple markers added. how to fix it and why it only happens in a large tablet screen?! clustering the markers is not a solution in this particular app and the marker are all shown in the projected area (all are visible to the user).

Comment: 100 markers should never be an issue with the map - but to answer your question, the larger screen size will have a greater screen pixel dimension so will display a greater area for any given zoom when comparing.  Is your code doing work on map movement?

Comment: only in `onMapStart` (which only checks to see if it is due to user gesture or not) and `onMapIdle`